# The file address is reduplicated in the vscode terminal every time I run code with python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I run any code (PYTHON) on the vscode terminal it is interpreted **next to the file address**. The problem is that this text fills too much space.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2iDO.jpg)

Is there any way the code is interpreted **uninterrumpted** every time I run code?

Comment: then write a task that runs it like you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no direct way to cancel the display of the path of the VS Code terminal, because this is the path where VS Code uses python and execution files in the integrated system terminal.

You could use the following settings in "launch.json":

```
"console": "internalConsole",
```

then
click `F5`:

[image]

Or you could use VS Code's extension "Code Runner" and add settings in "settings.json":

`"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,` then click the run button:

[image]